# How to print a box on top of another box in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

My goal is to make a chess board using assembly language so I'm trying to print a small gray box on top of a white bigger box, but the white box disappears as soon as the gray box is printed on the screen. I tried searching google but can't find an answer. Also, is there a better approach on making a chess board using assembly?

Here's my code.

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data
.code

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 11h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 0Ch
    mov dl, 28h
    int 10h

    mov cx, 10
    mov dx, 10
    mov ah, 0ch

    colcount:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 450
    JNE colcount

    mov cx, 10
    inc dx
    cmp dx, 450
    JNE colcount


    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 0Ch
    mov dl, 28h
    int 10h

    mov cx, 10
    mov dx, 10
    mov ah, 0ch

    colcount2:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx, 30
    JNE colcount2

    mov cx, 10
    inc dx
    cmp dx, 30
    JNE colcount2

end
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov ah, 0
> mov al, 11h
> int 10h
> ...
> mov ah, 0
> mov al, 13h
> int 10h
> ```

You reset the video mode between operations! No wonder the first box disappears.

---

- Why do you bother setting the cursor if you're only putting graphical pixels on the screen?
- You don't really seem to set the color anywhere. Goes in AL for function 0Ch.

Comment: How do I change the color of the smaller box without resetting the video mode?

Answer (score 1):

You've selected the 640x350 **2-color** screen.
The first box that you paint must be white. For now you obtain this by chance! As @Fifoernik said, you need to specify a color in the AL register.

```
mov cx, 10
mov dx, 10
mov ah, 0ch
mov al, 1    ;This is white on a 2-color screen!
colcount:
...
```

To solve the issue, first remove these 5 lines:

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov ah, 0
mov al, 13h
int 10h
```

Now paint the smaller black box by specifying AL=0

```
mov cx, 10
mov dx, 10
mov ah, 0ch
mov al, 0    ;This is black on a 2-color screen!
colcount2:
...
```